# Non standard OneToOne relationship problem in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I have two tables: Product and ExternalProduct.
A product can be an External Product and an External Product is related to a Product.

Despite the fact that is intuitive to put a foreign key from Product to ExternalProduct this is the minimal reproduction of a more complex scenario where this is not possible.

So ExternalProduct have a foreign key to Product.
At this point Entity framework generates the following code:

Product.cs:

```
public virtual ICollection<ExternalProduct> ExternalProduct { get; set; }
```

EF Mapping for ExternalProduct:

```
 builder.HasOne(d => d.Product)
            .WithMany(p => p.ExternalProduct)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProductId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("ExternalProduct_Product_Id_fk");
```

And That's technically correct because EF, having a foreign key from ExternalProduct to Product thinks that is a one to many relationship, **but**, In my case there will only be one ExternalProduct for a Product.

How can I modify the configuration to achieve this goal?

Comment: _"of a more complex scenario where this is not possible."_ -  you will need to explain this scenario and **why** it is not possible to put the key.

Answer (score 0):

You either have relation between two entities or not. If you have one-to-one relationship between `Product` and `ExternalProduct` then you need corresponding column/property on both sides of the relationship. Another option is (zero or one)-to-one, then you can declare nullable property on the (zero or one) side of the relationship:

```cs
class Product
{
    public virtual int? ExternalProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual ExternalProduct? ExternalProduct { get; set; }
}
```

Also there is a possibility you should look into using [inheritance hierarchy options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) available in EF Core.

If all of those are not suitable for you (i.e. it is highly likely there is no actual relationship here) - then remove relationships on both sides (and may be add some indexes).